# How to divide CGST and SGST in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to divide SGST and CGST in equal amount. currently on my site there is showing total tax amount of SGST and CGST on subtotal total. I need it should be show equal CGST and SGST amount. for more details see below snap

**Result Updated**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits  : [Magecomp link](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/)

To bifurcate **GST** taxes to show separately in all the order related documents, go to

go to and copy `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\order\tax.phtml`

```
<?php if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount); ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and paste at `app\design\frontend\[theme_package]\template\tax\order` And replace code as shown below:

```
<?php //if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php //echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount / ($percent/(float)$rate['percent']) ); ?>
                </td>
            <?php //endif; ?>
```

Now you can see you can see the detailed tax charges with the bifurcation of **SGST and CGS**T taxes in **cart, checkout, invoice, credit memo, shipment, my account order view and Emails.**

**Result** :

[image]

Comment: i go through same process but still it showing total tax of SGST and SGST

Comment: please have a look on my updated result

Comment: @Neeya if it is not live site, can you enable `template path hints` and check from which file that CGST and SGST values are displaying in checkout page.....

Comment: tax details showing from frontend\base\default\template\tax/checkout/tax.phtml

Comment: @Neeya take backup of the file and than do the same changes in that file as mentioned in that link and check once.....

Comment: after adding suggested changes in frontend\base\default\template\tax/checkout/tax.phtml it is not moving to order review step

Comment: @Neeya try with code  : https://pastebin.com/5eHp7znq in tax.phtml

Comment: hey its working...you are awesome. thank you so much for your help

Comment: glad it helped for you, you are also awesome :)

Comment: if you have any idea please answer to this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190214/how-to-display-gst-tax-calculation-on-wishlist-page-in-magento

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64281/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-neeya).