# How to display tax amount separately in Magento 2?

Tags: tax, magento2.2.4

I want to configure tax rule separately but showing tax rate amount is the addition of tax rule. I want to show the tax amount separately on the checkout summary page and order summary.

Result:-

[image]

Expected output:-

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve it? any guidance from you will be super helpful.

Comment: I hope this will helps you [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189932/how-to-divide-cgst-and-sgst-in-magento)